# Exim: run script after receiving from specific email account

Tags: shell, email, exim

I'd like to run a shell script when receiving emails from certain email account.

I am putting together a sms alert system whereby sending emails to alerts@domain.com, it runs a script that converts those emails to sms messages.

The script part is quite simple since I've got quite experience on it, but I have no idea about how trigger a script just when sending emails to a certain account.

Comment: set up an alias user and start up script , however this method is very old and not secure.

Comment: Hi @michael can you be more specific? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: ask your admin for   /etc/aliases/  or search google

Comment: @michael my point is, why I need to set up an alias user? how your suggestion is related to my question?

Answer (score 0):

If your exim configuration allows pipe transports from a .forward file, you can also put the following command in a `~/.forward` -file for the account in question:

```
|/path/to/script
```